# How to give Backslash as replacement in R string replace

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I need to ">" with "\". 
Example : "a>b" should be changed to "a\b"

I have tried gsub

```
> test <- "a>b"
> gsub(">","\\",test, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "a\\b"
```

I have tried StringR str_replace

```
> library(stringr)
> str_replace(test,">","\\")
[1] "ab"
```

I have tried Stringi str_replace_all_fixed

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_replace_all_fixed(test,">","\\")
[1] "a\\b"
```

How do I escape \ in replacement. I guess when you give \, it is expecting \1, \2 etc for captured groups. How to avoid this

Comment: try `cat(gsub(">","\\",test, fixed = TRUE))` you'll see there actually is only one backslash

Comment: @Cath, Thanks a lot.. My Bad.. been banging my head over this